# find decimal in a given number

Tags: java

How can i find decimal(dot) in a given number in java.

I am getting input from user, he may give integer or float value.

I need to find he entered integer or float, is it possible?

if yes could u tell me please.

--
Thanks

Comment: getting input from user - is this via a GUI or from a text file?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you got the digits of the number in a `String`, it would be

```
String number = ...;
if (number.indexOf('.') > -1)
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with `yourNumberString.indexOf(".")`. If it returns a number greater than -1 there's a dot in the input.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to explicitly search for the location of the decimal point as some answers suggest.  Simply parse the `String` into a double and then check whether that double represents an integer value.  This has the advantage of coping with scientific notation for doubles; e.g. "1E-10", as well as failing to parse badly formatted input; e.g. "12.34.56" (whereas searching for a '.' character would not detect this).

```
String s = ...
Double d = new Double(s);
int i = d.intValue();

if (i != d) {
  System.err.println("User entered a real number.");
} else {
  System.err.println("User entered an integer.");
}
```

Comment: Your int isn't going to be equal to the Double in a lot of cases even if the input was an integer.  Floating point isn't that precise.  You need to convert the int back to a Double and check for closeness (within 1.0e-6).

Answer (score 1):

Anticipating your need, I would suggest that you use [`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for number parsing, and use its `hasNextXXX` methods instead of dealing with `parseInt` etc and deal with `NumberFormatException`.

```
    import java.util.*;

    String[] inputs = {
        "1",
        "100000000000000",
        "123.45",
        "blah",
        "  "
    };
    for (String input : inputs) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            int i = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("(int) " + i);
        } else if (sc.hasNextLong()) {
            long ll = sc.nextLong();
            System.out.println("(long) " + ll);
        } else if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            double d = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("(double) " + d);
        } else if (sc.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("(string) " + sc.next());
        }
    }
```

This prints:

```
(int) 1
(long) 100000000000000
(double) 123.45
(string) blah
```

Answer (score 0):

Some other ways to do this:

given

```
String input = ...
```

the following evaluates to true if it's a decimal number

```
input.split(".").length == 2
```

or

```
input.matches(".+\\..+")
```

or

```
!input.matches("\\d+")
```